# How can I parse a scrapy response immediately after yielding a request?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Let's say that I am trying to scrape a website that is designed so that every request that it receives must contain a valid third party string key. Imagine that if you send a request that doesn't contain a valid key, the website will reply with an empty string.
So far, this is what I have:

```
class mySpider(Spider):

    #nicesite.com contains a list of items that are stored in my problematic website. It can be accessed without any key
    start_urls = ['http://www.nicesite.com']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #Let's say that every time I get new credentials I'm billed $1. Also assume that getMyCredentials() will generate new credentials every time it is called 
        self.credentials = getMyCredentials()

    #parsing nicesite.com
    def parse(self, response):

        #imagine that myList contains 50000 items --> I can't get new credentials for each item. That would be very expensive
        myList = response.selector.xpath('xpath_that_yields_the_items_Im_interested')
        for i in myList:
            myKey = requestToAThirdPartyService(self.credentials)
            yield Request('http://naughtysite.com/items/' + i + '/?' + urlencode(myKey), callback=self.parseItem )

   #parsing naughtysite.com
   def parseItem(self, response):

       if(response.body == ''):
            print('Dang! We lost an item because our key isnt valid anymore.')

            #update our credentials so the next items wont be lost as well
            self.credentials = getMyCredentials() 
       else:
           #collect the relevant data and yield item:
           item = response.selector.xpath('relevant_xpath')
           yield item
```

The problem I'm having is rather obvious: parseItem is not called after each Request is yielded, but after ALL the requests were yielded. This is why the first n items are being generated successfully and all the rest are not. After my key starts being rejected by the naughty website, it is never updated and keeps being rejected.

What I would like to do is to call parseItem immediately after yielding each Request so that it would be possible to know whether the response was empty and if so, update my credentials. With updated credentials I would have no problems with subsequent requests.
Can someone please help me to accomplish this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between generating a request and the request being actually sent a long time can pass. Requests are stored on a scheduler and consumed according to settings like [`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=per_domain#concurrent-requests) and [`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=per_domain#concurrent-requests-per-domain).

You should not include the keys on your spider. Instead, write a [custom downloader middleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#writing-your-own-downloader-middleware) that adds a key to your requests right before they are sent out.

Comment: I am new to scrapy and have never done anything with middlewares, so I might be asking a silly question. But what if my keys somehow depended on the items I retrieved from nicesite.com? If I added those items to the request's meta, for instance, would I be able to access them in the middleware class? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you would. You get access to the the `Request` object, and can access `request.meta`.